# Extra button on title bar for Swing GTK L&F

Tags: java, swing, gtk

Anyone know of anyway to add an extra button next to the general maximize, minimize, restore, and close button on the title bar in Swing GTK L&F? Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to need a lot of looking at the source. Probably forcing you down the clone-and-own route.

GTK is particularly difficult because the emulated engine reads look descriptions from XML files. So you are going to need some heuristics to guess where to place the button given the locations of others. Of course, you could assume a particularly look and slap a button down in a fixed position.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to make the window "borderless" and make your own "titlebar" (adding
it on top of the JFrame).
Of course you have to construct all the buttons on your own and emulate
all other titlebar functions.

The result will be cross-platform and it will work on all L&F regardless
if GTK+ or not.